# Can an Indian citizen/resident invest in a US company and collect the profits in India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, foreign-income

I have Indian residence and want to invest money by investing in an existing business in the USA. The total investment is $650k USD under a single name or $350k under two names.

I / We are procuring this fund by means of Mortgage loan. Every month I will get a return in from my share of the profit which would be used for repayment of capital and interest in India.

My concern is regarding RBI rules and regulations, FEMA guidelines, and Income tax.

Comment: Borrowing to invest is generally regarded as a poor idea. See for example [Borrow money to invest in a business venture with equity?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/81002/35567)

Answer (score 1):

> Every month I will get a return in from my share of the profit which would be used for repayment of capital and interest in India.

Not to sure what the business plan is. Please factor all the modalities, Exchange rate fluctuations, etc.

> My concern is regarding RBI rules and regulations, FEMA guidelines, and Income tax.

Under the [Liberalized Remittance Scheme](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10192&Mode=0); Funds can be transferred outside India. Any profit you make will be taxable in India. You will have to declare this pay tax in as per schedule.